# Unable to resolve import of DroidGap

Tags: android, cordova, jar, import, cordova-plugins

I know there are many existing questions and answers for my this question but none of them solved my problem.

```
DroidGap can not be resolved to a type
```

I tried below ways but none of them solved my problem.

Way 1:

Added `import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;` line in the import section, no luck.

Way 2:

Went to `Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Added cordovan.9.0.jar` Then went to `Order & Export->Checked jar & assigned to Top`, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer. Downloaded cordova-2.4.0.jar from java2s.com. Imported & ordered in eclipse. It worked for me.

Comment: you should use cordova 3.5.1 or geater if you want to submit your apps to google play. DroidGap no longer exists